# Can we update iceberg table from AWS lambda function using Python API of Iceberg?

Tags: database, amazon-s3, lambda, python-3.10, apache-iceberg

My AWS lambda generates a pandas Data Frame after some transformations in my data so I was just looking to
update my iceberg table directly with this pandas Data Frame object by using Python Iceberg API

Need some ways to do the same.. and is it Even possible to do this, as I didn't found any existing or prewritten blog on the same

Answer (score -1):

Here's some code that might help you achieve that (you need to install `iceberg` before that):

```
import iceberg
import pandas as pd
from iceberg.types import Types

# Initialize Iceberg Table
table = iceberg.Table.load("path/to/iceberg/table")

# Create a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie']
})

# Convert DataFrame to Parquet
df.to_parquet("temp.parquet")

# Append Data to Iceberg Table
with table.new_append() as append:
    append.append_file("temp.parquet").commit()
```

Comment: This does not work for me.

I believe the official Python Iceberg API is "pyiceberg" and not "iceberg" which appears to be an unrelated project. And it doesn't appear to contain the append_file functionality.